# Search MySQL table for a kind of results

Tags: mysql

How can I search within a MySQL table for results ending in anything except ".jpg"?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to involve regular expressions, you can just do:

```
SELECT my_fields
FROM my_table
WHERE my_field NOT LIKE '%.jpg'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   myfield NOT RLIKE '\\.jpg$'
```